# progress bar to deplete over time

Tags: progress-bar, progress

I'm trying to build an application that represents a game with progress bars decreasing by certain amounts depending on what buttons are pressed.

1. I've created the progress bar but I'm not sure of the code used to decrease the bars over time (slowly)
2. I dont know the code that allows (while depleting slowly) the progress bars to go up and down depending on the buttons pressed.
3. I also want to be able to change an image inside a jLabel to a 'bad guy' when the corrisponding progress bar is below 50 and a 'goodguy' at 50 or above.

Is this doable?

Comment: It is obviously doable, one way or another. But if you want to get some answer, you should at least add some relevant tags about what language and UI do you use (HTML with jquery, or java with swing, or whatever you use). Also, please fix your lower-case "i"s to proper uppercase "I"s and use [some paragraphs](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: And "is this doable" without any show of attempt on your part is not the best question - it may get some answers, or it can get a lot of down-votes and close-votes because it shows that you [haven't done enough research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Answer (score 0):

https://jqueryui.com/progressbar/

OR

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html

Please specify which language you refer to. Since you also talked about jLabel I suggest to read up on the upper link.